# Does System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard bug corrupt MS Office applications?

Tags: clipboard

I have discovered a bug in System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard that corrupts MS Office applications--like Outlook, Access and Excel--when Clipboard.Clear() is called from Forms programs running on the Win 7 x64.  It is a very serious bug, causing the MS Office programs to corrupt their databases--such as outlook.pst--and stop running with the " has stopped" message displayed to the user.

I can supply an exemplar program that will consistently produce this error.  I also have a simple work-around:  Do not call System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.*; reference presentation core and substitute a call to System.Windows.Clipboard.* instead.

MS implements the System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard class via unmanaged code through a COM interface.  Their Office applications apparently access the same COM object, and that is how the corruption occurs.